# Memory leak in layoutsubviews

Tags: ios, memory-management, uitableview, memory-leaks

When I scroll in my UITableView, `rateView` is == nil and memory is allocated for every cell. Is this a memory leak? Or is ARC automatically releasing the memory when the cell scrolls off the screen and allocating new memory for the next cell's 'rateView'?

This code is located in `layoutSubviews` of my my custom cell:

```
if (_rateView == nil) {
    _rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 7, 175, 50) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
    _rateView.padding = 8;
    _rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentRight;
    _rateView.editable = YES;
    _rateView.delegate = self; 
    [_clearRateViewBg addSubview:_rateView];
}
_rateView.rate = _userRating.intValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare _rateView as strong

And also you need to ensure that you're reusing the cell properly.